# Error: Metadata version mismatch for module found version 4, expected 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to run my Ionic app in release mode but am getting a strange error. The app runs fine in non-release mode.

> Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /Users/jscotto/Documents/projects/ionic_app/node_modules/ionic-audio/dist/ionic-audio-interfaces.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3

I'm using a plugin called `ionic-audio` which seems to use Angular 5, my app uses angular 4 but what doesn't make sense is why it would only not work in release build mode.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: You cannot mix versions like you are. If there is a version of the plugin that works with Angular 4, use that. Or, update your application to Angular 5.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it would work without release mode though. One would think if it's a compatibility issue, neither would work.

Comment: One *would* think (and be wrong sometimes). Dev builds are far more forgiving than prod builds. One good reason is so the transpiler doesn't have to do all that *prod build work* every time a save happens while running `ng serve`. The checks like what you see in the error may not run during a dev build. The v4 angular/compiler cannot handle components coded in v5 in a lot of cases now. It is one of the breaking changes between v4 and v5.

Comment: If updating my project isn't an option and the plugin doesn't have angular 5, is there any possible way to bypass it when running prod?

Comment: None that I am aware of. I mean, other that running an application in live with a dev build. I know you don't want that. Sorry!

Comment: I guess I'll have to attempt updating to angular 5 then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading my plugin to Angular 4 worked.